# Modify login.html file in Django

Tags: html, django

```html
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<section id="homeSection" style="width: 1250px;height: 1080px;padding: 40px;background-repeat: no- 
   repeat;background-position: top center;background-size: cover;">
   <div >
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <form method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

This HTML code is used for the login page. I need to modify the login page with CSS and bootstrap files. I am a beginner to DJANGO. Please suggest me how to modify the this login.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap cdn link in base.html